# adding a Router in spring integration application

Tags: spring-integration

I need to add a router in Spring integration application. The requirement is to either to send the message by the router to both the channel or to a single channel based on the return string sent by the router class. please tell me how to route the message to both the channels.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please read the [chapter on routers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router) and come back if you have a specific question.

Comment: Hi Gary Russell. The doubt is : A Router can direct the message to single or multiple channels based on the condition. I could not find out how to send message to more than one channel under one condition. let say if the bean returns the value "A" I need to send the message to Channel-A and if the bean returns value "B"  need to send the message to Channel-A and Channel-B both.  The bean decides to send "A" or "B" based on payload parameter. Can this be done using the router alone.if yes,then how do I define Channel-A and Channel-B (both) on return of value "B".  An XML example will be helpful

Comment: I returned a collection of channels from the bean. So it worked now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of a [Splitter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/splitter.html) and a [Header Value Router](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-headervaluerouter) to duplicate and route messages.

```
<!-- Clone message -->
    <int:splitter ref="messageDuplicator" method="duplicateMessage"
                  input-channel="incomingMessage" output-channel="duplicateMessageChannel" id="messageSplitter"/>

    <int:header-value-router input-channel="duplicateMessageChannel" header-name="DESTINATION" id="messageDestinationRouter">
        <int:mapping value="DEST_1" channel="dest1Channel" />
        <int:mapping value="DEST_2" channel="dest2Channel" />
    </int:header-value-router>
```

In your *messageDuplicator* implementation, you can add code to clone your message and add custom headers for routing the message to different destinations.